# HBase: how to view the last integrated rows?

Tags: hbase

I have a Spark job that converts CSV into parquet and stores into HBase. I want to see if the integration works well.

The rowkey starts with "2019-09-11-xxxxx", but when I do `scan 'namespace:mydb',{FILTER => "PrefixFilter('2019-09-11')"}`, it starts to scan from the very first row and I wait for more than a few hours, it's still running and nothing appears.

I think it's also possible to check the lastest `timestamp`, but I'm not sure how to do this.